# Print data between two TAGS using AWK or SED

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have text file contain followig pattern

```
<SUBBEGIN
NAME : A ;
AGE : 10 ;
ADDRESS 1 : NO10;
ADDRESS 2 : X-Lane;
ADDRESS 3 : X-City ;
CITY : X-City;
<SUBEND
<SUBBEGIN
NAME : B ;
AGE : 30 ;
ADDRESS 1 : NO70;
ADDRESS 2 : Y-Lane;
ADDRESS 3 : Y-City ;
<SUBEND
```

i want to print above output as below format, please be kind enough to help me to sort this, i am new for bash/shell

Expected Output :

```
NAME : A ;AGE : 10 ;ADDRESS 1 : NO10;ADDRESS 2 : X-Lane;ADDRESS 3 : X-City ;CITY : X-City;
NAME : B ;AGE : 30 ;ADDRESS 1 : NO70;ADDRESS 2 : Y-Lane;ADDRESS 3 : Y-City ;
```

i tried following 2 codes but both are print above data without TAG

```
awk  'BEGIN { FS = "<SUB" } ; { gsub(" ","",$0); print }' users.txt
```

and

```
awk '/<SUBBEGIN/{flag=1;next}/<SUBEND/{flag=0}flag' users.txt
```

Comment: do you have any lines outside of `<SUBBEGIN` and `<SUBEND` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RS` is changed to `"<SUBBEGIN|<SUBEND"`. So anything between these tags would be considered as one record.

```
awk -v RS="<SUBBEGIN|<SUBEND" '{$1=$1;} /./{print $0}' inputfile
NAME : A ; AGE : 10 ; ADDRESS 1 : NO10; ADDRESS 2 : X-Lane; ADDRESS 3 : X-City ; CITY : X-City;
NAME : B ; AGE : 30 ; ADDRESS 1 : NO70; ADDRESS 2 : Y-Lane; ADDRESS 3 : Y-City ;
```

Comment: Alternatively you could do `'NF>1{$1=$1; print}'` to remove blank lines.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/<SUBEND/{print t;t="";next}!/<SUBBEGIN/{t=t?t" "$0:$0}' file
```